# Is python dict.copy() not working properly?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I was making configuration program to help the users configurate a `.json` file. One of the feature of the program was to check if the saved `json` is the same as the a new `json` file made by the user. If the two `.json` are not the same, it will tell the user to save the `.json` file that is being configurated in the program.

My first thought was to read from the `.json` file every time when checking if the two `.json` files are the same. It looked something like this:

```py
# read from the saved json file
new_settings = {"key1": 1, "key2": 2, "array1": []} # json.load(open('config.json', 'r').read())
# modifying new_settings
new_settings['array1'].append('Data')

def checkIsDifferent():
    # read from the saved json file
    saved_settings = {"key1": 1, "key2": 2, "array1": []} # json.load(open('config.json', 'r').read())
    if saved_settings == new_settings:
        print('Configuration is saved')
    else:
        print('(*)Configuration is not saved')
```

I don't think constantly reading from a file will be good way to compare the "settings" in my case, so I came up with another way, by copying the saved `.json` to a variable, and then use the variable to compare:

```py
saved_settings = {"key1": 1, "key2": 2, "array1": []} # read from the saved json file
new_settings = saved_settings.copy()

# modify
new_settings['array1'].append('Data')

def checkIsDifferent():
    if saved_settings == new_settings:
        print('Configuration is saved')
    else:
        print('(*)Configuration is not saved')
```

The first solution went expected. It outputted "(*)Configuration is not saved" when running `checkIsDifferent()` function. But when I run `checkIsDifferent()` on the second solution it outputted "Configuration is saved".

Is `dict.copy()` in python broken? How can I fix it for the second solution?

#### System Environment:

Python version: Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)]

OS: Windows 10

Comment: `dict.copy()` performs a "shallow" copy: `saved_settings['array1']` and `new_settings['array1']` are both references to the same list and the append is affecting both. Use [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) instead

Comment: Pretty sure you need to make a deep copy for them to be different.  The pointer to the list will be copied, but the list will be the same.

Comment: When you call copy it will take "key1" and allocate new memory for 1 because 1 is immutable (its an integer).  But when it takes "array1" it won't allocate new memory for [] because lists are mutable.

Comment: @LPR Python also has to allocate memory for empty lists.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, you are correct, but when you perform copy in this manner, it will be the same list in both dictionaries.  It will not create a new list.

Answer (score 2):

copy() will only copy references to anything that is not of a primitive type. Use deepcopy instead.

```
from copy import deepcopy

saved_settings = {"key1": 1, "key2": 2, "array1": []} # read from the saved json file
new_settings = deepcopy(saved_settings)
# modify
new_settings['array1'].append('Data')

def checkIsDifferent():
    if saved_settings == new_settings:
        print('Configuration is saved')
    else:
        print('(*)Configuration is not saved')
```

Comment: What do you mean by the first sentence? A list is a collection of references to other objects and copy will duplicate those references no matter the underlying type

Comment: I think copy also copies references to "primitive types" (which I'm not sure this concept even exists in Python). Everything is an object and lists contain references to objects.

Comment: @IainShelvington Sorry, that was worded poorly. Yes it will copy the list, but everything inside the list that is not a primitive type (int, float, chr, str) will only be referenced

Comment: @rabl that's not the case at all, objects that are those "primitive" types will also only be referenced

Comment: @IainShelvington
take a look at this code; I just tested it with Python3 and the assertion failed, which means it is not passed by reference for type int:
`import copy;
list = [2, 3];
reference = copy.copy(list);
list[1] = 6;
assert(reference[1] == list[1];`

Comment: @rabl your code changes the object referenced at `list[1]` of course your assertion is not going to pass. This code shows that a copied list and the original have the same reference to an int: `list = [1000000]; reference = copy.copy(list); assert id(list[0]) == id(reference[0])`

Comment: @IainShelvington If it were passed by reference (by memory adress of the variable) then the content of both lists would change.

Comment: @rabi No it wouldn't. `list[index] = foo` changes the object referenced at that position in the list

Comment: That is just how the = operator works. If you had an object that overloaded the = operator or you would change the contents of the object using a function, then the object would still be the same for both lists. See this example: https://pastebin.com/ig1npHV9

Comment: @rabl you are misunderstanding how Python works. All "variables" (names) are just references to objects, assigning a different object to a name doesn't change the contents of anything it just changes the reference that the name holds. The `id` function returns the id of the object that a name references, try it: `a = 'foo'; print(id(a)); a = 'bar'; print(id(a))`. Or using lists: `l = [None]; s = 'abc'; id(l[0]); id(s); l[0] = s; id(l[0])`

Comment: You are right. I assumed for type int (and other primitives) the \_\_assign__ function would just store the value that is passed to the function, as that would be faster than referencing. Sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: @rabl no worries :) you're right, it probably would be more efficient, it's one of many reasons that Python is pretty slow!